# Discord.py on_typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've got some issues using discord.py. I'd like to use on_typing event for logging or something, but it doesn't work. I've tried to do this

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Here is all code. on_ready and on_message works fine but on_typing. How to make it work?

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    logger.info("But successfully runned!")

@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
    logger.info("{} is typing message in {} : {}".format(user.name, channel, when))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    logger.info("{} has just sent {}".format(message.author, message.content))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is your mistake:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

do not write the line `intents.typing = True`, just enable all intents at the beginning. To do that, you would delete the `intents.typing = True` line, and then replace the `intents = discord.Intents.default()` with `intents = discord.Intents.all()`, and then that's it (Make sure you've enabled intents in the [Discord Dev Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications))! Depending on your bots ping, it won't detect typing immediately, but a few milliseconds after. So, the ending code would look something like this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

And then you calling the `on_typing` event is correct! Hope this helped! If you have any follow up questions about my code or unforeseen errors feel free to follow up!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the `on_typing` event and the `on_message` event with `@client.listen` such as:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    logger.info("But successfully runned!")

@client.listen
async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
    logger.info("{} is typing message in {} : {}".format(user.name, channel, when))

@client.listen
async def on_message(message):
    logger.info("{} has just sent {}".format(message.author, message.content))
```

I came across this issue when I was making a join message this seemed to fix it.

Comment: `@client.listen()` should be written with the parenthesis, and optionally with the string included of the event it's listening to, such as: `@client.listen('on_message')` and that will allow you to name the actual function something else, so that you can have multiple distinguishable event listeners